# Easy trig problem. An impossible angle.

Tags: trigonometry

I was helping a friend and we encountered a particularly confusing problem.

In triangle ABC, side a = 12, b = 16, and sinB = 2/3. What is the measure of angle A in degrees?

The answer is 30, but I have no idea how to arrive at that answer. If A were 30 degrees, then that would make triangle ABC a 30-60-90 triangle, but that would render sinB = 2/3 impossible as $\sin(60) = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}.$ Am I missing something, or is the problem worded incorrectly?

Comment: Ｄｏ　ｙｏｕ　ｋｎｏｗ　ｓｉｎｅ　ｌａｗ？

Comment: How did you conclude that the triangle has an angle of $90°$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mick says, you need the sine law (and additionally you have to know that the angle opposite the longest side is the biggest).

It says $\frac{sin(A)}{sin(B)}=\frac{a}{b}$

So, we have $sin(A)=sin(B)\cdot\frac{12}{16}=\frac{1}{2}$

$A$ cannot be $150°$ because then $a$ would have to be the longest side, which is not the case. Hence, we must have $A=30°$.

Comment: I am not sure whether a solution can be made only using triangles with an angle of $90°$